# Comparing each element in two columns and set another column

Tags: r

I have a data frame (after fread from a file) with two columns (dep and label). I want to set another column (mark) with id value depending on the match. If the  'dep' entry matches 'lablel' entry, mark get the 'id' of the matched 'label'. For no match, mark get the value of its own 'id'. Currently, I have work around solution with loops but I know there should be a neat way to do it in R specifics.

```
trace <- data.table(id=seq(1:7),dep=c(-1,45,40,47,0,45,43), 
label=c(99,40,43,45,47,42,48), mark=rep("",7))
   id dep label mark
1:  1  -1    99  1    
2:  2  45    40  2  
3:  3  40    43  2   
4:  4  47    45  4  
5:  5  0     47  5   
6:  6  45    42  4  
7:  7  43    48  3
```

I know loops are slow in r and just to give example the following naive for/while works for small sizes but my data set is huge.

```
trace$mark <- trace$id
for (i in 1:length(trace$id)){
val <- trace$dep[i]
j <- 1
while(j<=i && val !=-1 && val!=0){ // don't compare if val is -1/0

    if(val==trace$label[j]){
            trace$mark[i] <- trace$id[j]
                    }
 j <-j +1
}
}
```

I have also tried using the following approach but it works only if there is a single match.

```
match <- which(trace$dep %in% trace$label)
match_to <- which(trace$label %in% trace$dep)
trace$mark[match] <- trace$mark[match_to]
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution might help:

```
trace[trace[,.(id,dep=label)],mark:=as.character(i.id),on="dep"]
trace[mark=="",mark:=as.character(id)]
# id dep label mark
# 1:  1  -1    99    1
# 2:  2  45    40    4
# 3:  3  -1    43    3
# 4:  4  47    45    5
# 5:  5  -1    47    5
# 6:  6  45    42    4
# 7:  7  43    48    3
```

**Update:**

To make sure you are not matching `dep` with `0` or `-1` values you can just add another line.

```
trace[dep %in% c(0,-1), mark:= as.character(id)]
```

**OR**
Try this:

```
trace[trace[!dep %in% c(0,-1),.(id,dep=label)],mark:=as.character(i.id),on="dep"]
trace[mark=="",mark:=as.character(id)]
```

**The solution that worked**

```
trace[trace[,.(id,dep=label)],on=.(id<=id,dep),mark:=as.char‌​acter(i.id),allow.ca‌​rtesian=TRUE]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: ok, so running  above for my actual data set (2581691 rows) results in following error. Where should I specify by=.EACHI?


Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation.

Comment: Use this option `trace[trace[!dep %in% c(0,-1),.(id,dep=label)],mark:=as.character(i.id),on="dep",allow.cartesian=TRUE]`

Comment: allow.cartesian=TRUE results in the same error. Whereas using the following option is running without error. Not sure, will it succeed but not giving error for last few minutes 
    trace[trace[!dep %in% c(0,-1),.(id,dep=label)],mark:=as.character(i.id),on="dep",by=.EACHI]

Comment: @Saltaf can you provide some part of data that can reproduce that error? You can use `dput(mydata[10:30])` or something similar to it.

Comment: Not sure, how to provide that data. The problem only shows up with hundred thousand record size. Partial data runs without issues.

Comment: any idea what change will be required if I want to get the updated output ? Basically, what the loop is doing, running only for j<i and not for all i values.

Comment: @Saltaf Do you want to take this over a chat? Because I can't really help without reproducing the error.

Comment: @A Gore, it is partially resolved as I am doing it in two batches now.

Comment: @Saltaf I found one more idea. See if it works... `trace[trace[,.(id,dep=label)],on=.(id<=id,dep),mark:=as.character(i.id),allow.cartesian=TRUE]`

Comment: If this solves your problem, you can close the question by accepting his answer (check mark to the left)